# Which Google Oauth 2.0 Client ID type choose for cordova hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing cordova based hybrid mobile apps targeted for android and iOS smartphones.

**Usecase:** The application authenticate user and then would be accessing Google Calendar API's, and finally display user events on the app.

**Note:** I will be Using 3-legged OAuth and Google Data APIs without the client libraries.

**Question**

The Cordova-enabled WebView provides the application with its entire user interface, so what should be the **application type** in this case?

- Since everything is going inside webview, so Shall  I choose "Web Application"?

OR

- Do I need to create seperate Applications type for Android and iOS
  seperately?
- Or can iOS Application Type work for both Android and iOS?

Please suggest what should be the proper approach to choose application type in this case.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just an unrelated heads up https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html  you will probably need to use the OS browser not a webview with Google Oauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your app is setup. If you plan on handling all of the OAUTH processing on a backend server then you can use the Web application type, and you can have all the OAUTH work offloaded to the backend server.

If you do not have a backend server and will do all OAUTH processing on the user's device, then you should create both an iOS and Android client ID. For example:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

This plugin's documentation shows the creation of both an iOS and Android client ID to enable Google Sign In on a Cordova app.